# advice on structuring templates for a nested collection 

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a tree structure in mongo with each node having the id of its parent. Something like this:

```
{ "_id" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, "parent" : 1 }
```

And the whole tree is rendered by rendering each node recursively using these templates:

```
<template name="thing">
      <div class="project open {{status}}" data-id="{{_id}}" id="thing_{{_id}}">
          <div class="name">{{name}}</div>
          <div class="children" id="children_{{_id}}">
              {{> childrenThings }}
          </div>
      </div>
</template>

<template id="childrenThings" name="childrenThings">
    {{#each children}}
      {{> thing}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

where the template "thing" calls the template "childrenThings" which calls the template "thing" again and so on until all nodes are re-rendered.

Now when i change a nested item, I see that ALL nodes until its root parent are re-rendered. How should I set up the templates so that only the current template is rerendered and not all of its parent nodes until the root?

Thanks :)

Comment: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_ui_chunk May do what you want. ```If the data used to generate that substring changes, only the elements corresponding to that substring will be updated, not the elements before and after it.```

Comment: @lashleigh That link is dead, and I am looking for a similar fix. Any idea?

Comment: @Tyrsius No, unfortunately. I haven't done any Meteor in the past few months and it has been evolving rapidly; up to v0.5.4 now I see and I think this comment was posted for v0.3.5. I'd probably have to reread the docs to get caught up. http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

When child templates re-render, they fire the parent's rendered callback. So it doesn't mean your entire parent tree has literally been taken off the DOM and put back on. It just means that *some* DOM node inside the template's range has been rendered. This is a bit confusing. If you're noticing flickering, or some other weird behavior, that's different. But your code looks okay to me.